# `git` - could not able to create `achive` existing repo

Tags: git, git-archive

I am trying to export my existing `git` repo  with following command. But I end up with errors. any one help me to fix this?

my command :

```
PS F:\Nissan-Gulp> git archive --format zip --output F:\convert master
fatal: could not create archive file 'F:\convert': Is a directory
PS F:\Nissan-Gulp>
```

my existing `git` project at `Nissan-Gulp` and I wish to send to `'F:\convert':` folder. but not works.

Answer (score 1):

The `F:\convert` path should be a file, not a directory. Create that directory and run the command with `F:\convert\FILENAME`, replacing `FILENAME` with what you'd like to name the archive.

Comment: I tried, but still not the file created for me. my it like : ` git archive --format zip --output F:\convert\new` - new is the file name what I would like ti create in the `F` - folder.

Comment: Even though that creates the files, still the file size is `0KB` - how to fix this?

Comment: Finally I tried like ` git archive --format zip --output F:\new master ` - it works fine. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This error message is also displayed when a file called `FILENAME` already exists, but is owned by a user whose files you cannot overwrite. (At least on 'nix-y systems.)

E.g:

```
# whoami
root
# touch release1.zip
# su schmuck
$ git archive Release1 --format zip -o release1.zip
fatal: could not create archive file 'release1.zip': Permission denied
```

I ran into this problem attempting to make an archive as the root user, forgetting that I was root and that the root user didn't have a proper Git config, then attempting to make an archive as a regular Joe:

```
# git archive Release1 -o release1.zip
fatal: unsafe repository ('/var/www/repo' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory /var/www/repo
```

Note that `git archive` makes an empty file *before* this "unsafe repository" check is made.

```
# find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*" -printf "%f\t%s\t%u\n"
foo             100 schmuck
bar             50  schmuck
baz             200 schmuck
release1.zip    0   root
.gitignore      100 schmuck
```

And predictably, `schmuck` cannot overwrite `root`'s file:

```
# su schmuck
$ git archive Release1 -o release1.zip
fatal: could not create archive file 'sprint2.zip': Permission denied
```

Simply delete the file as root, then proceed with the archive.

```
$ sudo rm release1.zip
$ git archive Release1 -o release1.zip
```